# add multiple gmap marker

Tags: google-maps, vue.js

i have a vue2-google-map apps that display map.

before this i using this code

```
        <GmapMarker
          ref="myMarker"
          :position="google && new google.maps.LatLng(1.38, 103.8)"
        />
        <GmapMarker
          ref="myMarker"
          :position="google && new google.maps.LatLng(3.1488976, 101.6126774)"
        />
```

to display multiple marker, but if the latlng data is too many, it will be many  need to be create.

my idea is to take data from

```
const latlng = [
{
  lat: value,
  lng: value,
},
{
  lat: value,
  lng: value,
},
```

and apply `{{latlng}}` into `<GmapMarker :position="google && new google.maps.LatLn({{latlng.lng}},{{latlng.lat}})">`

but i have problem to apply that {{latlng}} into the marker.
can someone explain how to apply them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For generating multiple markers your need to push latitude and longitude in the marker collection and then iterate the marker.i have updated code as per the requirement.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <GmapMap
      ref="gmap"
      :center="getCenter()"
      :zoom="11"
      style="height: 500px;margin: 0px -8px;"
      class="no-padding"
      :options="getOptions()"
    >
      <GmapMarker
        :key="index"
        v-for="(m, index) in getMarkers()"
        :position="m.position"
        :clickable="true"
        :draggable="false"
        :title="m.title"
        :icon="m.icon"
        @click="clicked()"
      />
    </GmapMap>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
import MarkerClusterer from "marker-clusterer-plus";
export default {
  name: "SiteMap",
  props: [],
  methods: {   
    getOptions() {
      return {
        zoomControl: true,
        mapTypeControl: false,
        scaleControl: false,
        streetViewControl: false,
        rotateControl: false,
        fullscreenControl: false,
        disableDefaultUi: false
      };
    },
    clicked() {
     // after click
    },
    getCenter() {     
          return {
            lat: 37.12523,
            lng: -122.1252
          };
    },
    getMarkers() {
      // generating markers for site map
        var markers = [];
        // remove this after lat long received from api.
        const tempLatLong = [
          { lat: 37.9068361, lng: -122.116971 },
          { lat: 37.9168362, lng: -122.076972 },
          { lat: 37.9268363, lng: -122.136973 },
          { lat: 37.9368364, lng: -122.146974 },
          { lat: 37.9468365, lng: -122.106975 },
          { lat: 37.9568366, lng: -122.166976 },
          { lat: 37.9668367, lng: -122.176977 },
          { lat: 37.9768368, lng: -122.016978 },
          { lat: 37.9868369, lng: -122.196979 }
        ];
       for(let i=0;i<tempLatLong.length;i++){
          markers.push({
              position: tempLatLong[i],
              title: 'test title',
              icon: this.getSiteIcon(1)    // if you want to show different as per the condition.         
            });
        }
        return markers;      
    },
  getSiteIcon(status) {
      try {
        switch (status) {
          case 1:
            return require("@/assets/images/icons/map-marker-online.svg");
            break;
          case 2:
            return require("@/assets/images/icons/map-marker-critical.svg");
            break;
          case 3:
            return require("@/assets/images/icons/map-marker-offline.svg");
            break;
          case 4:
            return require("@/assets/images/icons/map-marker-lifesafety.svg");
            break;
          default:
            return require("@/assets/images/icons/map-marker-online.svg");
        }
      } catch (e) {
        return null;
      }
    },
  },
  components: {},
  created() {},
  mounted() {
  }
};
</script>
<style scoped></style>
```

Comment: this worked perfectly, thank you sir for this sharing. can i refer this code for changing markers icon>

Comment: Happy to help !!

Comment: how about if my lat and lng retrieve from api, but the variables is 'latitude' and 'longitude' not lat/lng. is there any where i can set for markers to read the 'latitude' and 'longitude' instead of lat/lng

Comment: I haven't tested this.but you can modify data as per the gmap specification.

Comment: yes i have modify the code and it's succeed with API data where i'm using for loop to retrieve all the api data and store latitude and longitude into its new variable. thanks again for your above explaination.